# Hapi AssertionError: Cannot set path parameters validations without path parameters: GET

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hapi.js

This happened when i tried moving to hapi v17..

This is my endpoint

`{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/admin/pagetypes',
    handler: Handlers.index,
    config: {
      description: 'get page types',
      tags: ['api'],
      auth: {
          strategy: 'standard',
          scope: 'admin'
      },
      validate : {
        params : {
          p: Joi.number().default(0),
          message: Joi.string().empty(''),
          filter: Joi.string().empty(''),
          keyword: Joi.string().empty(''),
          by: Joi.string().empty(''),
          field: Joi.string().empty('')
        }
      }
    }
  },`

when starting my hapi server it says

> { AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Cannot set path parameters validations without path parameters: GET /admin/pagetypes
>       at new module.exports.internals.Route (/Users/computer/Documents/proj/api/node_modules/hapi/lib/route.js:128:14)

Tried removing the validate and it runs but that's not what i want

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to validate path parameters, but your path definition has no parameter in it.

Here: `path: '/admin/pagetypes',`

I think you are trying to validate your query parameters which will be added to your path like this: `/admin/pagetypes?p=1&message=Hello` etc.

If you are, try this. This will validate your query parameters.

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/admin/pagetypes',
    handler: Handlers.index,
    config: {
      description: 'get page types',
      tags: ['api'],
      auth: {
          strategy: 'standard',
          scope: 'admin'
      },
      validate : {
        query : {
          p: Joi.number().default(0),
          message: Joi.string().empty(''),
          filter: Joi.string().empty(''),
          keyword: Joi.string().empty(''),
          by: Joi.string().empty(''),
          field: Joi.string().empty('')
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

To validate path parameters you need to some dynamic values to your path definition like

`path: '/admin/pagetypes/{pageId}',`

**pageId** here is a path parameter then you can use
`validate.params` to validate that parameter.

[Here is the reference](https://hapijs.com/api#path-parameters)